# Rails: https:// for a specific URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, nginx

I am developing an e commerce site. Working on Ruby on Rails.Nginx is using as web server and unicorn as application server. In my application I want to implement ssl only for the payment page,means only for a specific url. I tried to configure my on way. I am using gem **'rack-ssl-enforcer'**. The gem configuration I gave as below in my environment file

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer,
 :redirect_to => 'https://demo.domain.com',    # For when behind a proxy, like nginx
 :only => [/^\/payment\//],                      # Force SSL on everything behind /admin   and /authors
 :strict => true
```

And I configure my nginx as given below. I have provided two server block one for common **http://** and one for **ssl(https://)**.

```
upstream unicorn_domain {
 # This is the socket we configured in unicorn.rb
server unix:/home/ubuntu/root_path/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=30;
} 

server {
listen 80;
client_max_body_size 4G;
server_name demo.domain.com;

keepalive_timeout 5;

# Location of our static files
root /home/ubuntu/1DRecruit/root_path/public;
access_log /home/ubuntu/root_path/log/nginx/nginx.access.log;
location / {


  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;

  # If you don't find the filename in the static files
  # Then request it from the unicorn server
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_domain;
    break;
  }

  if ($request_uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)\?[0-9]+$") {
    expires max;
    break;
  }

}

}

 server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    ssl                   on;
    ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com_chain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols         SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers           ALL:-ADH:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP;
    ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:10m;


    keepalive_timeout 5;
# Location of our static files
    root /home/ubuntu/root_path/public;
   location / {
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;

}

}
```

After configuring like this the nginx is not showing any error while restarting and when we take the site it is loading properly. But when we go to the payment page the url is changing to **https://** but it showing and nginx error **404 Not found**. When taking the nginx error log the error showing is

```
[error] 2532#0: *1 open() "/home/ubuntu/root_path/public/payment/make_payment" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 110.235.112.69, server: , request: "GET /payment/make_payment?id=9 HTTP/1.1", host: "demo.domain.com", referrer: "http://demo.domain.com/posters/home"
```

I am using startssl for certificate. I cant figure out the problem. And it is very important to fix the problem.Can anyone help me in this issue.

Thank You,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

/app/middlewares/force_ssl.rb

```
class ForceSSL
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    path = env["PATH_INFO"].to_s.squeeze("/")

    # only force ssl on billing related requests
    if path.match(/^\/installations\/\d+\/billing/) && env['HTTPS'] != 'on' && env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] != 'https'
      req = Rack::Request.new(env)
      [301, { "Location" => req.url.gsub(/^http:/, "https:") }, []]
    elsif !path.match(/^\/installations\/\d+\/billing/) && !path.match(/^\/facebook\//) && (env['HTTPS'] == 'on' || env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
      req = Rack::Request.new(env)
      [301, { "Location" => req.url.gsub(/^https:/, "http:") }, []]
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

I hope it works for you. Let me know

Comment: Thank you for the replay.Sorry...am not clear.Confused with the reg exp you mentioned. In my case what should I use.Can you suggest any document related to this or elaborate little more base on my scenario.